# Click <div> to open Drop Down Not working in IE and FireFox

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have a jquery function where I can Click and it will bring a Drop Down . Every thing is fine but this is not working in IE and Firefox . When I click nothing happen or No Drop Down Comes up .

Here is The Example from Js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LwLsZ/

Not finding way to solve that . If any Expert can Solve the Problem it Will be Great

**HTML**

```
<div id="gear">
Click Me

<div id="dropdown">  </div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
#gear {
margin: 100px;
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid;
position: relative;
}

#dropdown {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right: -1px;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid;
display: none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){

$('html').click(function(){
    if($('#dropdown').is(':visible')){
       $('#dropdown').hide(); 
    } 
});

$('#gear').click(function(){
   event.stopPropagation();
   $('#dropdown').toggle(); 
});

 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `event` parameter to the event listeners.  Change your jQuery code to be

```
$(function(){
    $('html').click(function(event){
        if($('#dropdown').is(':visible')){
           $('#dropdown').hide(); 
        } 
    });

    $('#gear').click(function(event){
       event.stopPropagation();
       $('#dropdown').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

and it should work.  I [forked your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8EkJa/1/) to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `stopPropagation` to a `return false` and put it to after the toggle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LwLsZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

change it to this:

```
$(function(){

 $(document).click(function(){
   if($('#dropdown').is(':visible')){
    $('#dropdown').hide(); 
   } 
 });

 $('#gear').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('#dropdown').toggle(); 
 });

});
```

`$(document)` take care that it will work in IE